# Eclipse NetSuite SuiteScript Plugin Cannot Create New Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have been trying to configure eclipse to work with the NetSuite IDE plugin. When I try to create a new project after installing the plugin, I receive the following error message:

> Problem Occurred: org/eclipse/wst/common/componentcore/ModuleCoreNature

This is the error window shown in [eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwX4h.png)

And you can find my error log [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Des9.png)

I am very new to NetSuite and don't work with Eclipse often. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The error log is *text*, not an image of a view. It's located under your workspace's directory, as `{workspace directory}\.metadata\.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some documentation in a recent NetSuite study guide for SuiteScripts that said that the Eclipse IDE is now deprecated. Webstorm also has integration with the NetSuite plugin that you could try

OR you might be able to use whatever IDE you want and just copy stuff over. Might be more work but that seems to be the current state of things as far as I can tell.